# Can't select child elements using getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript

Here is the HTML code:

```
<span class="holder">
    <a href="/menu/page1">Navigate</a>
</span>
```

I want to select all such tags with class holder and then under these holders I want to change  href of `a` tag.

What I have tried:

```
var holders = document.getElementsByClassName('holder'),
    i = holders.length;

while(i--) {
    holders[i].getElementsByTagName('a').href = "http://www.google.com";

    }
```

But the above code does not work. It does not change the href from `/menu/page1` to my custom link.  What am I doing wrong?

As I am working with some external web page,I cannot use jquery. 
Only Javascript solutions please. 
Thank You.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, you have to iterate over it.

Comment: @user3127499 You don't need to comment just to say you've answered, the questioner is automatically notified when their questions get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the perent element may contain multiple instances of a same tag, so `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of the elements/nodes

So, you have to process it like an array. Bellow is one of the best way to do this

```
var holders = document.getElementsByClassName('holder'),
    i = holders.length;

while(i--) {
    var anchors = holders[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var j = 0; j < anchors.length; j++) { 
        anchors[j].href="'http://www.google.com";
    }

}
```

### **Demo Fiddle**

Answer (score 4):

getElementsByTagName returns elements collection, if you want to get the first link, use `.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]`